# Trying to get webpage source a second time throws exception - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer

> Error message - NotSupportedException was unhandled 
>   `{"Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01B6"}`

Above error is encountered even if the same url is being tried to get the webpage source a second time to variable `Strj`. Please assist if there is a way around.

I have already tried:

```
source = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(cURL)
```

but this is not an option for me.

```
Dim cURL As String = "D:\abc.html"
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate(cURL)
Do While IE.ReadyState <> tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE : Application.DoEvents() : Loop

Dim Strj As String

    Strj = IE.Document.body.innerHTML

    IE.Navigate(cURL)
    Do While IE.ReadyState <> tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE : Application.DoEvents() : Loop

    Strj = IE.Document.body.innerHTML  '--> Error here
```

Comment: Wait. What do you mean "This is not an option for me" ?

Comment: Does the `source = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(cURL)` work ?

Comment: Hello Ban, Yes the above line works for me.. but I want to achieve the fuctionality using IE object. It is strange that the same code works for first time but errors out the second time. Please help me here.